# GKE NodePort service refusing incoming traffic

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a Node port service in Google cloud with the following specification...    I have a firewall rule created to allow traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 for the port '30100' ,I have verified stackdriver logs and traffic is allowed but when I either use curl or from browser to hit  http://:30100 I am not getting any response. I couldn't proceed how to debug the issue also... can someone please suggest on this ?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginxv1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginxv1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginxv1
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30100
  selector:
    app: nginxv1
  type: NodePort
```

Thanks.

Comment: Curious about this: `curl or from browser to hit http://:30100`. If it is nodeport, do you need to curl the IP address of the node?

Comment: Yes Brian....  I have used the Public IP of the node that is part of the cluster I created. I curled to that node from my local system.

Comment: Did you take care of firewall? eg gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-node-port --allow tcp:30100

Comment: If you stuck you can get some ideas here to troubleshoot: https://github.com/DanyLan/GKE-EXPOSE-SERVICES/blob/master/NodePort.md

Comment: add output of `kubectl describe svc nginxv1`

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the container port, it must be `80` because the nginx container exposes this port as you can see [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginxv1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginxv1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
---    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginxv1
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30100
  selector:
    app: nginxv1
  type: NodePort
```

Also, you need to create a firewall rule to permit the traffic to the node, as mentioned by @danyL in comments:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-node-port --allow tcp:30100
```

Get the node IP with the command

```
kubectl get nodes -owide
```

And them try to access the nginx page with:

```
curl http://<NODEIP>:30100
```

Comment: kubectl get nodes -o wide

Comment: Thank you KoopaKiller and Dany L and all others who helped. This worked after changing containerPort to 80 .